# OpenGL ES apply fragment shader to the entire GLFW screen

Tags: opengl-es, glfw, fragment-shader

I want to apply my OpenGL ES shaders to my entire GLFW screen. I have a few textures on the window and I made a black&white filter using a fragment shader and I want that filter to cover the entire window, including the textures on the screen.

How can I achieve this? Is it possible? Are there any work-arounds?

Comment: Framebuffers? Example: https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers